# How to structure functional code in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

I'm wondering what is the best way to structure functional code in Kotlin.

I don't want to create unnecessary objects (and put functions in a closed scope) to group my functions with. I heard I can group functions by packages and put them in the top level of a package. I've also seen in Arrow library that functions are grouped in interface companion objects as extension functions and this looks the best except the fact I need to create a companion object.

Object way:

```
object Container {
    fun myFunc() = ...
}

...

Container.myFunc()
```

Package way:

```
package myPackage

fun myFunc() = ...

...

myPackage.myFunc()
```

Arrow way:

```
interface Container {
    companion object {
        fun Container.myfunc() = ...
    }
}

...

Container.myFunc()
```

What is the best way to structure my functions and group them using Kotlin? I want to keep a pure functional style, avoid creating any sort of objects, and be able to easily navigate to functions by namespaces like:

`Person.Repository.getById(id: UUID)`

Comment: If you want to call functions using namespaces like that, you do need to create objects (or companion objects). You could create a top-level package named Person with a subpackage named Repository and put top-level functions there,  but this isn't really idiomatic Kotlin.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for the concept of **namespaces** (structured hierarchical scope for accessing symbols).

Kotlin does not support namespaces, but as you found out, there are different ways of having similar functionality:

1. **`object` declarations.** They pretty much fulfill the needs, however they lead to creation of an actual object in JVM and introduce a new type, which you don't need. The Jetbrains team [generally discouraged the use of objects as namespaces](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/best-practices-for-top-level-declarations/2198), but it's of course still an option. I don't see how companion objects inside interfaces add any value. Maybe the idea is to limit the scope to classes which implement the interface.
2. **Top-level functions.** While possible, top-level functions in Kotlin pollute the global namespace, and the call-site does not let you specify where they belong. You could of course do workarounds, but all of them are rather ugly:

   - Fully qualify the package `com.acme.project.myFunc()`
   - Use a deliberately short, but no longer domain-representing package `functional.myFunc()`
   - Call function without package, but with prefix `package_myFunc()`
3. **Extension functions.** If the functionality is closely related to the objects it's operating on, extension functions are a good option. You see this for the Kotlin standard collections and all their functional algorithms like `map()`, `filter()`, `fold()` etc.
4. **Global variables.** This does not add much over the `object` approach, just prevents you from introducing a named type. The idea is to create an anymous object implementing one or more interfaces (unfortunately, without interfaces the declared functions are not globally accessible):

   ```
   interface Functionals {
       fun func(): Int
   }

   val globals = object : Functionals {
       override fun func() = 3
   }
   ```

   It is mainly handy if your object implements different interfaces, so that you can pass only a part of the functionality to different modules. Note that the same can be achieved with `object`s alone, as they can implement interfaces too.

Comment: This is a few years old now, but I'm wondering if anyone has new insights or if any patterns have become "standard" since this question and answer.

It seems that the most common approach I've encountered is to just use a top-level `object` as a namespace, which I hate.

Also, I think the interface + companion approach is intended to avoid being able to pass around the top-level object. It might make more sense if the companion were marked @JvmStatic. Then maybe there would be no objects instantiated?

Answer (score 1):

In my own code, I mostly opt for using top-level functions in appropriately organized packages.

The problem, as other answers/comments point out, is that those top-level functions really pollute your IDE's (IntelliJ IDEA- let's be honest) completion suggestions all throughout your code-base. This is really frustrating and unwieldy in a large project.

But, honestly, that's more of a problem with how IDEA does completions than of the approach, IMO. If IDEA prioritized completion suggestions by "package-proximity" or something, I think this approach would be much more convenient.

The other reason the top-level function approach is awkward is because of how packages and imports are handled in Kotlin (which is basically the same as Java except that Kotlin does have import aliases, which is nice). The problem is that you can't import a package, itself; you can only import "things" **in** a package. If you could import the package as its own thing, you could just use the package as a namespace, which is kind of what they're supposed to actually **be**, anyway.

In other words, if you have a function called `myFunc()` in package `com.company.project.feature`, then to call your `myFunc()` from another package, you have to either import `com.company.project.feature.myFunc` and call it as `myFunc()`, or you have to just call it by its fully qualified name of `com.company.project.feature.myFunc()`. If we could import a package as a namespace, we could import `com.company.project.feature` and call the function like `feature.myFunc()`, which would be **so** much nicer.

But, alas, we don't have that. So, for these two reasons, it's very common to just create top-level `object`s to be used as namespaces. But, I absolutely hate that on principle because an `object` is both a real JVM object that has to be allocated and take up memory for the lifetime of your program's execution and can be passed around and manipulated, and is also a new type/class, which doesn't really hurt anything but is also extra meaning that we're not trying to express.

I've never seen the approach you call "the Arrow way", and I'm not sure it's correct the way you've written it. When you write the extension function on `Container`, it means that the function is only callable on *instances* of `Container`, so you wouldn't be able to do `Container.myFunc()`. You'd have to either remove the `Container` as a receiver to `myFunc` or make the companion object implement the `Container` interface itself.

In any case, I tried a few variations on the object-as-namespace approach, and looked at the resulting Java bytecode to see which ways might minimize allocations or useless memory overhead. The tl;dr answer is that it mostly doesn't matter. All five of my approaches instantiate at least one object allocation, but some of them may require fewer indirections when called.

Here are my five approaches:

```
interface Foo {
    companion object {
        fun foo() {
            println("foo")
        }
    }
}

interface Foo2 {
    companion object: Foo2 {
        fun Foo2.foo2() {
            println("foo2")
        }
    }
}

interface Bar {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun bar() {
            println("bar")
        }
    }
}

object Baz {
    fun baz() {
        println("baz")
    }
}

object Qux {
    @JvmStatic
    fun qux() {
        println("qux")
    }
}
```

Each variation looks the same from the call sites:

```
Foo.foo()
Foo2.foo2()
Bar.bar()
Baz.baz()
Qux.qux()
```

Here's the decompiled bytecode after I removed a bunch of annotations and metadata for the sake of focus:

```
public interface Foo {
    @NotNull
    Foo.Companion Companion = Foo.Companion.$$INSTANCE;

    public static final class Companion {
        static final Foo.Companion $$INSTANCE;
    
        public final void foo() {
            String var1 = "foo";
            System.out.println(var1);
        }
    
        private Companion() {
        }
    
        static {
            Foo.Companion var0 = new Foo.Companion();
            $$INSTANCE = var0;
        }
    }
}

public interface Foo2 {
    @NotNull
    Foo2.Companion Companion = Foo2.Companion.$$INSTANCE;

    public static final class Companion implements Foo2 {
        static final Foo2.Companion $$INSTANCE;
    
        public final void foo2(@NotNull Foo2 $this$foo2) {
            Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter($this$foo2, "$this$foo2");
            String var2 = "foo2";
            System.out.println(var2);
         }
    
        private Companion() {
        }
    
        static {
            Foo2.Companion var0 = new Foo2.Companion();
            $$INSTANCE = var0;
        }
    }
}

public interface Bar {
    @NotNull
    Bar.Companion Companion = Bar.Companion.$$INSTANCE;

    @JvmStatic
    static void bar() {
        Companion.bar();
    }

    public static final class Companion {
        static final Bar.Companion $$INSTANCE;
    
        @JvmStatic
        public final void bar() {
            String var1 = "bar";
            System.out.println(var1);
        }
    
        private Companion() {
        }
    
        static {
            Bar.Companion var0 = new Bar.Companion();
            $$INSTANCE = var0;
        }
    }
}

public static final class Baz {
    @NotNull
    public static final Baz INSTANCE;

    public final void baz() {
        String var1 = "baz";
        System.out.println(var1);
    }

    private Baz() {
    }

    static {
        Baz var0 = new Baz();
        INSTANCE = var0;
    }
}

public static final class Qux {
    @NotNull
    public static final Qux INSTANCE;

    @JvmStatic
    public static final void qux() {
        String var0 = "qux";
        System.out.println(var0);
    }

    private Qux() {
    }

    static {
        Qux var0 = new Qux();
        INSTANCE = var0;
    }
}
```

And the call sites end up looking like this:

```
Foo.Companion.foo();
Foo2.Companion.foo2((Foo2)Foo2.Companion);
Bar.Companion.bar();
Baz.INSTANCE.baz();
Qux.qux();
```

So, for all five variants, there is one object created and held in memory.

For `Foo`, the function call goes through one indirection (gets the companion object and calls its instance method).

For `Foo2`, the function call does the same as for `Foo`, except it also passes the companion object instance as a parameter to its own method call. This is clearly the worst approach from the POV of the machine doing pointless operations.

Humorously, the `Bar` variant *could* be implemented more efficiently (it could avoid using the companion instance altogether, but it doesn't). So, this is the same as the `Foo` approach, meaning that adding `@JvmStatic` didn't actually help us.

The `Baz` generates less code, but is otherwise probably the same as `Foo`.

Now, `Qux` is the only one that's actually slightly different than the others. This time the `@JvmStatic` annotation actually helped up, because the call site just calls the static method directly, so no indirection at all. The performance will be the same as calling a top-level Kotlin function. The singleton instance of the `Qux` object is still created and taking up memory, but we don't actually access it at all to make calls to the static methods.

So, if I were to use any of these methods it would either be the `Baz` or `Qux` approaches. Mostly likely we should just go with the `Baz` approach, because adding the `@JvmStatic` annotation is extra noise and **probably** won't ever cause any noticeable performance difference. Plus, the empty interface approach is weird, anyway. What would it even mean if a class somewhere implemented the interface?